# Apollo Subscription Server returns "Must provide document."

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Our firm migrated yesterday to Apollo v3 (apollo-server-express v3.4.0).

Unfortunately, subscriptions return the following response:

```
{ "message": "Must provide document" }
```

We made following observations:

1. This is a server issue, as we experience this error with Apollo Studio too.
2. The connection is established, as the server fires the onConnect event.
3. The request fires the onOperation event with the right message.
4. The subscribe event of the subscription is however never called.

This is my index.mjs:

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import cors from 'cors';
import { execute, subscribe } from 'graphql';
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload';
import { SubscriptionServer } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';

import typeDefs from './moduleHandler/graphqlModule/typeDefs.mjs';
import resolvers from './moduleHandler/graphqlModule/resolvers.mjs';


const expressApp = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    callback(null, true);
    return;
  },
  credentials: true
};

expressApp.use(cors(corsOptions));
expressApp.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ }));

const httpServer = http.createServer(expressApp);

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const subscriptionServer = SubscriptionServer.create({
  schema,
  execute,
  subscribe,
  onConnect: async (connectionParams, webSocket) => { // subscriptions
    console.log('on Connect')  // fires
    return { }
  },
  onOperation: async (_message, params, ws) => {
    console.log(_message)  // fires
    /* prints my subcription:
        {
    id: '23',
       type: 'start',
       payload: {
         query: 'subscription Subscription($category: ConversationOverviewCategory!) {\n' +
           '  conversationOverviewListen(category: $category) {\n' +
           '    item {\n' +
           '      base { _id }\n' +
           '    }\n' +
           '  }\n' +
           '}',
         operationName: 'Subscription',
         variables: { category: 'ALL' }
       }
     }
    */
    return params;
  }, {
  server: httpServer,
  path: '/subscriptions'
});

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  playground: false,
  resolverValidationOptions: {
    requireResolversForResolveType: false
  },
  formatError: err => {
    console.log(err); // not called
  },
  plugins: [{
    async serverWillStart() {
      return {
        async drainServer() {
          console.log('bye');  // not called
          subscriptionServer.close();
        }
      };
    }
  }],
  uploads: false,
  path: '/graphql'
});

await apolloServer.start();
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app: expressApp, cors: corsOptions, path: '/graphql' });

httpServer.listen(80, async () => {
  httpServer.setTimeout(1 * 60000) // 1 min
  console.log('started');  // called
});
```

My resolvers.mjs:

```
export default {
  Subscription: {
   conversationOverviewListen: {
    subscribe: () => console.log("never called"),
  }
};
```

We are happy for any help. Thank you!!

Comment: Did you ever solve this without downgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to apollo-server-express v3.1.2 solved this issue.